# Symfony bundle configuration - conditional definitions

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony documentation has such description (check the bold part):

> When loading multiple configuration files, it should be possible to
> merge and overwrite some values. Other values should not be merged and
> stay as they are when first encountered. **Also, some keys are only
> available when another key has a specific value** (in the sample
> configuration above: the memory key only makes sense when the driver
> is sqlite).
> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html

This is exactly what I need. I want to make some configuration kay available (and required) only under specific condition. But there is no example or any information how to achieve such thing in documentation.

Example yaml:

```
my_bundle:
   storages:
      storage_name_1:
         type: TYPE_A         # Always required
         connection: default  # Always required
         path: somepath       # Required and available only if 'type' is TYPE_A
      storage_name_2:
         type: TYPE_B
         connection: default
```

Example configuration:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('storages')
            ->isRequired()
            ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->arrayPrototype()
                ->children()
                    ->enumNode('type')
                        ->values(['TYPE_A', 'TYPE_B'])
                        ->isRequired()
                        ->cannotBeEmpty()
                    ->end()
                    ->scalarNode('connection')->isRequired()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('path')->isRequired()->end() // This should be required AND available only if type is TYPE_A. TYPE_B should not have this parameter.
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Comment: For the moment, I kwon you can set a default value to path

Comment: I think it might be a misinterpretation; the `memory` key has a default value when not `sqlite`. Look down the page for `memory` and you'll see `->booleanNode('memory')->defaultFalse()`. What they're referring to there is the `memory` key itself is optional (default to `false`).

Comment: I don't know how "some keys are only available when another key has a specific value" could be misinterpreted in such way. This for sure doesn't mean "some keys can have default value and may be omitted".

Comment: Consider trying the Slack Symfony channel (from the Symfony Community) page or take a deep breath and look at how some of the other bundles do it.  The configure tree is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Not saying it's great phrasing, but it seems to suggest that the configuration doesn't require the `memory` key for anything but the parent `sqlite`, so it can be defaulted (e.g, maybe `null`) and somebody doesn't have to include what isn't always required. I would think you'd need a callback with config-row/parent access or to rearrange it so it's more like `mysql`, `sqlite` (`TYPE_A: ...`) in nature and can be defaulted when unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could map different types as their own connection subset. This would be whatever your type's adapter would need to work.

```
my_bundle:
    storage:
        TYPE_A:
            -   name: storage_1
                connection: default
                path: somepath
        TYPE_B:
            -   name: storage_2
                connection: default
```

Guessing a bit, should be something like this.

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('storage')
            ->isRequired()
            ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
            ->arrayNode('TYPE_A')
                ->arrayPrototype()
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayPrototype()
                            ->children()
                                ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end()
                                ->scalarNode('connection')->isRequired()->end()
                                ->scalarNode('path')->isRequired()->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode('TYPE_B')
                ->arrayPrototype()
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayPrototype()
                            ->children()
                                ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end()
                                ->scalarNode('connection')->isRequired()->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Comment: So you fliped it that type can have multiple definitions. Maybe less elegant but could work as expected. I will check that out and see how it works. Thank you!